# Django: Getting an Error Saying "needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used"

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner in Django. Right now, I am learning the framework by uilding an app, called PhoneReview. It will store reviews related to the latest mobile phone. It will also display phone brands, along with the associated phone models and their reviews.

When I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/index, I see this page:
[image]

When I click on **Samsung**, I see this page:

[image]

Up to this is fine.
But when I click on any phone model, like **Galaxy S10**, I get 404 error. It looks like this:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/details/galaxy-s10
Raised by:  PhoneReview.views.ReviewView
No review found matching the query

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

When I click on Samsung, I am supposed to see the **details.html** page, which has the review of the phone, along with the news link. Instead, I am getting the 404 error.

I thought that performing migration and adding a new review about any phone model, like Galaxy S10, through Django admin would fix the issue. But when I try to add a review for the Galaxy S10 through Django admin, I get this error:

```
"<Review: The Galaxy S10 is a fitting 10th anniversary phone for Samsung and its storied S series. It delivers on change with a novel-looking Infinity-O screen so large it displaces the front camera, and a triple-lens rear camera that takes ultra-wide photos. Its in-screen fingerprint sensor tech should serve you well, while its Wireless PowerShare could serve your friends well. That’s a lot of change – just know that it comes at a high price and the Galaxy S10e and S10 Plus flank it from both sides of the coin as better options.>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

Here are my codes of **models.py** located inside PhoneReview folder:

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

# Create your models here.
class Brand(models.Model):
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    origin = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    manufacturing_since = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.brand_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.brand_name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

class PhoneModel(models.Model):
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    model_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    launch_date = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    platform = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.model_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.model_name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

class Review(models.Model):
    phone_model = models.ManyToManyField(PhoneModel, related_name='reviews')
    review_article = models.TextField()
    date_published = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    link = models.TextField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.review_article

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.phone_model)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here are my codes of **urls.py** located inside PhoneReview folder:

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path

app_name = 'PhoneReview'

urlpatterns = [
    path('index', views.BrandListView.as_view(), name='brandlist'),
    path('phonemodel/<slug:slug>', views.ModelView.as_view(), name='modellist'),
    path('details/<slug:slug>', views.ReviewView.as_view(), name='details'),
]
```

Here are my codes of **views.py** located inside PhoneReview folder:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.views import generic
from .models import Brand, PhoneModel, Review


class BrandListView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'PhoneReview/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_brands'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Brand.objects.all()


class ModelView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'PhoneReview/phonemodel.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_model_name'

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.brand = get_object_or_404(Brand, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        return PhoneModel.objects.filter(brand=self.brand)

class ReviewView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Review
    template_name = 'PhoneReview/details.html'
```

Here are my codes of **apps.py** located inside PhoneReview folder:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class PhonereviewConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'PhoneReview'
```

Here are my codes of **index.html** located inside templates folder:

```
{% extends 'PhoneReview/base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block title%}
Brand List
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<!--Page content-->
<h1>This is Brand List Page</h1>
<h2>Here is the list of the brands</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for brand in all_brands %}
<!--            <li>{{ brand.brand_name }}</li>-->
            <li><a href = "{% url 'PhoneReview:modellist' brand.slug %}">{{ brand.brand_name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
<img src="{% static "images/brandlist.jpg" %}" alt="Super Mario Odyssey" /> <!-- New line -->
{% endblock %}
```

Here are my codes of **phonemodel.html** located inside templates folder:

```
{% extends 'PhoneReview/base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block title%}
Phone Model Page
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<!--Page content-->
<h1>This is Phone Model Page</h1>
<h2>Here is the phone model</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for phonemodel in all_model_name %}
            <li><a href = "{% url 'PhoneReview:details' phonemodel.slug %}">{{ phonemodel.model_name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
<img src="{% static "images/brandlist.jpg" %}" alt="Super Mario Odyssey" /> <!-- New line -->
{% endblock %}
```

Here are my codes of **details.html** located inside templates folder:

```
{% extends 'PhoneReview/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/style.css" %}">


<html lang="en">

{% block title%}Details{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<h1>This is the Details Page</h1>

<h2>Review:</h2>
<p>{{ review.review_article }}</p>

<h2>News Link:</h2>
<a href={{ review.link }}>{{ review.link }}</a>
{% endblock %}
</html>
```

Is there any problem in **details.html**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your review model save method is the issue. because `slugify(self.phone_model)` is executed before many to many field adding the value.

**try**

by commenting out save method for Review model

Comment: Thanks. Now, I can save the review of the phone model, which is Galaxy S10. However, I am still getting 404 error. Should I post a new question about it?

Comment: because your detaillview function dependent on slug but slug is disabled on many to many filed

Comment: would you please give me the working code? i am a beginner. I have spent a lot of time solving the 404 error. but I can't figure out the right codes that solve the issue. it will be really helpful for me if you give me the working codes.

Comment: or you can use id instead of the slug in phonemodel.html  <li><a href = "{% url 'details' phonemodel.id %}">{{ phonemodel.model_name }}</a></li>  and add pk_url_kwarg = "slug" to ReviewView class in views.py

Comment: i can make the codes work with id. but i need to use slug for better url readability. would you please help me to solve the issue with the slug? should i give my project files via Google Drive link?

Comment: wait i am trying to help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202429/discussion-between-givejob-and-shawn).